# Conversion from String to type Date is not valid error

Tags: .net, datetime

I have the following date as string "091020". I am using SubSonic as my DAL. When I do

```
myObject.DateColumn = "091020"
```

I get the error "Conversion from type String to Type Date is not valid"

I tried playing with the IFormatProvider and CultureInfo but can't seem to get raid of the error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
myObject.DateColumn = DateTime.ParseExact("091020", "yyMMdd", null)
```

[DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) lets you specify exactly how to parse the date when it's not entirely obvious.

Comment: I tried this earlier but got the error Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider

Comment: Got it! I was using DateTime.Parse

Comment: If I have the time as "1422" can I use DateTime.ParseExact to store the time in a System.Date object?

Comment: I believe so, but then the date defaults to DateTime.MinValue, which is, I believe, 1/1/0001 (January first, 1 A.D.)

Comment: The trick, then is to DISPLAY only the time portion. The easiest way to do this is by using DateTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss")

Answer (score 2):

.Net can't parse that into a valid date.  Throw this in a new project and verify that:

```
string sDate = "091120";
DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;

if (DateTime.TryParse(sDate, out dt))
    MessageBox.Show(dt.ToShortDateString());
else
    MessageBox.Show("Nope");
```

So, if you KNOW that all your dates are yyMMdd, then use this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("091120", "yyMMdd", null)
```

How are you getting these dates?  Are they guaranteed to be 6 digits in the yyMMdd format?